# how to make section 1 carousel horizontal and section 2 listview builder vertical

Tags: flutter, dart, infinite-scroll

how to make section 1 carousel horizontal and section 2 listview builder vertical with infintescroll flutter

[image]

I try using API and want create example news app there is a problem when combining with columns, horizontal and vertical and infinitescroll

Comment: Welcome to StakeOverflow. Please add what you've tried so, that everyone suggest changes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flutter_carousel_widget: package. Documentation for this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carousel_widget

You can also review my code as an example. (I didn't bother with the design, I just wanted to show you what it looks like when it works)

Example:

```
Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            FlutterCarousel(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                height: 200.0,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                showIndicator: true,
                slideIndicator: CircularSlideIndicator(),
              ),
              items: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].map((i) {
                return Builder(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.amber),
                        child: Text(
                          'text $i',
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                        ));
                  },
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
            Text("Just Another News"),
            Container(
              height: 300,
              child: FlutterCarousel(
                options: CarouselOptions(
                  autoPlay: true,
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  autoPlayInterval: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                ),
                items: [1,2,3,4,5].map((i) {
                  return Builder(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          child: Image.network('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1575936123452-b67c3203c357?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aW1hZ2V8ZW58MHx8MHx8fDA%3D&w=1000&q=80')
                      );
                    },
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
```

Output:

[image]

I hope I have helped.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, for section 2 using listview builder vertical with infinite scroll flutter, can make infinite scroll Is it possible in one page?